# Better way to Populate nested references mongoosejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to populate references nested within other references. I have it working but it seems kinda hacky and was wondering if there is any other way to accomplish this:

```
return Q.ninvoke(BoardSchema, 'find', {'_id': id}).then(function(board) {
    return Q.ninvoke(BoardSchema, 'populate', board, {path: 'lanes'}).then(function(board){
        return Q.ninvoke(LaneSchema, 'populate', board[0].lanes, {path: 'cards'}).then(function(lanes){
            board.lanes = lanes;
            return board;
        });
    });
});
```

Is there some method to populate all references, or return the second populate as part of the board call without manually setting it like I am now?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to populate multiple to populate nested documents like so:

```
Item.find({}).populate('foo foo.child').exec(function(err, items) {
    // Do something here
});
```

This requires that refs are setup in the Schema definitions.

If this doesn't work, which to be honest is most of the times for some reason, you can chain your finds. But this doesn't differ much from your code.

```
Item.find({}).populate('foo').exec(function(err, items) {
    Item.find(items).populate('bar').exec(function(err, items) {
        // Even more nests if you like
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Gideon, yea I can't seems to find a way to populate the second ref without chaining together calls. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response of Gideon

```
Item.find({ _id: id})
  .populate({
    path: 'foo',
    model: 'FooModel',
    populate: {
      path: 'child',
      model: 'ChildModel'
    }
  })
  .exec(function(err, items) {
  // ...
});
```